# Any good recommendation/resource for doing Branching in TFS (Team Foundation Server)?

Tags: tfs, branch

Branching always seems to be a complicated thing to do.  Not technically but yeah there are some real decisions/planning that goes in to come up with an appropriate branching strategy.

I know of this
[TFS Branching Guide](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSBranchingGuideII)

Any other resource or guideline which you recommend or use for branching and merge.

Sharing your experience in this area is really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only concentrate on resources that specifically reference TFS then you'll miss a huge amount of excellent content that is more general in nature or is even aimed at other source control systems. Given that you seem to be more interested in methodology rather than the technical implementation of TFS branching, it makes sense to look elsewhere - for example:

- You can find a good general source control tutorial [here](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html), which is written by Eric from [SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/)
- Jeff Atwood (one of the SO founders) talked about branching strategies in his Coding Horror [blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000968.html)
- SVN has an excellent - if slightly verbose - section on branching in its [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html)

Comment: I agree with this.  The TFS Branching guidelines are pretty good, but subversion's base structure is also good.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll definitely have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the patterns and practices branching document and have now started reading the [Team Foundation Server 2008 in Action](http://www.manning.com/azher/) from Manning.

I haven't got as far as the branching\merging strategy section yet in this publication but what I've read so far (related to the new build features in TFS 2008) have been pretty good!

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I will definitely have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Read this great introduction into the theory of branches, trunk etc: http://oreilly.com/catalog/practicalperforce/chapter/ch07.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think this a pretty refreshing view also [infoq](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control)